# initial values select2 v4 tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm having problems intialising the new select2 plugin with intitial values selected.

I'm populating the data from a data object (which I get from an ajax call). Then initialise select2.

Here's the html of the original select control:

```
<select class="tagsinput" multiple="multiple" name="tags[]">
    <option value="">Enter tags for the article</option>
    <option value="3" selected="selected">test</option>
</select>
```

Without select2 initialised this works as expected

My data is obtained via an ajax call to a database as follows:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/articles/tags',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                initTagsSelect(data);
            }
        });
```

And here is how I initiate the select2:

```
function initTagsSelect(data) {
            $('.tagsinput').select2({
                theme: "bootstrap",
                data: data,
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                tags: true,
                tokenSeparators: [','],

            });
```

This initialises the select and turns it into a tag field but the initial selection is lost. The text field is empty. I can see that all the tags supplied by the data call have been appended to the select field as additional options.

I'm struggling to find examples of the mew select4 in searches so not sure what I now need to do. I did see the new `current` option but was unclear about that.

**Update:**

I've created a jsbin for the problem: https://jsbin.com/lupafan/edit?html,js,output.

If I remove the data from the initialisation the initial values are created correctly - when I introduce the data object the intial values do not appear

Comment: What version of Select2 are you using? This may be a known bug.

Comment: Hi - version 4.01 - updated today but still not working

Comment: Try downgrading to 4.0.0 and see if the problem fixes itself. There's an issue with pre-selected values in 4.0.1.

Comment: Hi - I had the problem originally with version 4.0.0 and tried the upgrade to 4.01 to see it fixed it - problem exists in both versions